# What does “He has fat people hands” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

He has fat people hands, or at least the hands of custodian.

Comment: It means what it says.  What is unclear?  What is the source of this line of text.  What is the relevance of "custodian".  This question is not clear or useful at the moment.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, "fat people" is a compound noun being used as an adjective to describe someone's hands.

The inference is derogatory - it suggests that the hands of fat people (an offensive term in itself) have a certain identifiable look and that the person being referred to has those kind of hands. Without context I don't know if that means the person *is* fat has the hands to match, or if they just have hands *like* a fat person. Again, these can be offensive terms but it this is a genuine quote, that is how to understand it.